# Deliver docker container on the server with no internet

Tags: docker, cicd

I have a project which is written in Python. After I push it's going to be pulled by another team and after that they are going to deliver the project to windows server machine wich has no internet. It is going to be host on the windows server machine which is only accessable via local intranet. Is it possible to run all the installations on docker container during the CI/CD process and deliver that 'ready' container (not just an image) to the host? I'm using GitHub if that is important

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command to save an image to a tar archive in your CI/CD pipeline:

```
docker save image-name > image-name.tar
```

Then you can send that tar to your team. They can install that image to the air gapped server with [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

```
docker load --input image-name.tar
```